# How to solve this PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have faced the following equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2} - f(y,z) u(x,y,z)=0$$

When the arbitrary function does not depend on $x$, then it can be solved as an ODE problem with keeping $f$ as a parameter of $y$ and $z$:
$$u(x,y,z)=A_1(y,z)e^{f(y,z)x}+A_2(y,z)e^{-f(y,z)x}$$

That is fine!

But, what if we have an arbitrary function $f(x,y,z)$ instead of $f(y,z)$?

$$\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2} - f(x,y,z) u(x,y,z)=0$$

Any one can help me to solve it please?!

Thank you

Comment: Well, the same idea reduces this to an ODE of the form $u''(x) = f(x)u(x)$ with parameters $y,z$. I doubt you can get an explicit solution for this in terms of elementary functions unless $f$ is very special; but you can give the general form of a solution for the PDE in terms of the general solution for this ODE.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say .. Yes, exactly, the same strategy used in ODE should be applied here for this uni-variate PDE problem, where the independent variables $y$ and $z$ are taken as parameters :)